# C# sqlDataAdapter issue

Tags: c#, sql

all I try to load data from sql by following code using SQL server. I checked connection is normal and most sql are available to load. But in certain cases, I can't load data with following error:

**"The conversion of the varchar value '2863289685' overflowed an int column.
The statement has been terminated."**

and that sql is runnable in sql server management studio, but can't load by following code, please help me with possible solution, thanks!

```
           try
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                command.CommandTimeout = 0;
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                sqlDa.Fill(ds);
                Console.WriteLine(ds.Tables.Count);
                dt = ds.Tables[0];
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This issue relates to the SQL query, not the .NET code.  Such data conversion issues can be plan-dependent.

Comment: well obviously you're trying to convert some varchar into a int and the value is too big for an int
post the value of the var sql

Comment: not answer but fill to a datatable is simpler in your case. no need dataset.

Comment: What is your query? And please also add relevant table definitions. Side point: You need to dispose your connection, command and adapter with `using`

Comment: thank you for all comment, it seems that I use Right() function in SQL Server for queries like following: 
CASE WHEN PRBST.PrbCard <> '' THEN 'PC-' + RIGHT(1000000+PRBST.PrbCard,6) ELSE NULL END AS prb_card, after I write an alternate solution for this column without RIGHT function, the error is fixed.